# Very weird behavior of python print function: printing somehow changes the result of a function

Tags: python, graph, printing, networkx, isomorphism

I am trying to compare if two graphs are isomorphic using `networkx`. However, I found a very weird problem that got me confused for days. I have a function `get_graph` that takes the nodes, edge-starts and edge-ends as inputs. When I was debugging, I added a line `print(list(edges))` to print out the zipped `edges` in the function. Then I was shocked to find that this somehow changes the result of isomorphism. If you try my code below, you will find out that the two graphs are isomorphic if you add that line, but is not isomorphic when commenting out.

I don't think this has anything to do with `networkx` or graphs in general. This should be considered as weird behavior of the `print` function. As far as I am concerned, the `print` function should never change the result of a function. Anyone has any idea?

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as iso

def get_graph(nodes, edge_starts, edge_ends):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    edges = zip(edge_starts, edge_ends)

#    print(list(edges))

    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    return G

nodes1 = [(0, {'symbol': 'Ni'}), (1, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (2, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (3, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (4, {'symbol': 'Ni'}), (5, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (6, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (7, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (8, {'symbol': 'Ni'}), (9, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (10, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (11, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (12, {'symbol': 'Ni'}), (13, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (14, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (15, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (16, {'symbol': 'CH3'}), (17, {'symbol': 'OH'}), (18, {'symbol': 'CO'})]
starts1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18]
ends1 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 6, 8, 0, 5, 8, 9, 0, 1, 9, 10, 6, 7, 9, 11, 2, 7, 8, 12, 1, 4, 11, 12, 13, 4, 5, 8, 10, 13, 14, 5, 13, 14, 3, 6, 9]

G1 = get_graph(nodes1, starts1, ends1)

nodes2 = [(0, {'symbol': 'Ni'}), (1, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (2, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (3, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (4, {'symbol': 'Ni'}), (5, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (6, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (7, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (8, {'symbol': 'Ni'}), (9, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (10, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (11, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (12, {'symbol': 'Ni'}), (13, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (14, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (15, {'symbol': 'Pt'}), (16, {'symbol': 'CH3'}), (17, {'symbol': 'OH'}), (18, {'symbol': 'CO'})]
starts2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18]
ends2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 6, 8, 0, 5, 8, 9, 0, 1, 9, 10, 6, 7, 9, 11, 2, 7, 8, 12, 1, 4, 11, 12, 13, 4, 5, 8, 10, 13, 14, 1, 10, 11, 2, 7, 13]

G2 = get_graph(nodes2, starts2, ends2)

print(nx.isomorphism.is_isomorphic(G1, G2))
```

Comment: `print(list(edges))` is consuming all the data in the `edges` iterator. So it's empty when you call `G.add_edges_from()`.

Comment: I think that zip returns an iterable, so list(edges) has the side-effect of consuming it. print() has no real part here.

Comment: Ninja'd by @Barmar, you are consuming your generator